# How to make <li></li> with class-col-lg-4 to have width only of the content inside, not on the full 4 columns?

Tags: html, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have list of images  with class col-lg-4 and border around `<li></li>` element but if it in the container-fluid it have full width of 4 columns and border stretching on 4 columns, but I need that the border be only around image and not stretching on the full width.

On the first image is what I have: 
[image]

Second image is what I need to have:

[image]

My html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <ul class="row portfolio-images-list justify-content-center justify-content-md-around">
            <li class="portfolio-list-item img-border mix design col-lg-4">
                <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_first.png" alt="First Image">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="overlay-content">
                            <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
                            <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="portfolio-list-item img-border mix illustration col-lg-4">
                <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_second.png" alt="Second Image">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="overlay-content">
                            <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
                            <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="portfolio-list-item img-border mix motion col-lg-4">
                <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_third.png" alt="Third Image">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="overlay-content">
                            <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
                            <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="portfolio-list-item img-border mix web col-lg-4">
                <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_fourth.png" alt="Fourth Image">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="overlay-content">
                            <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
                            <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="portfolio-list-item img-border mix web col-lg-4">
                <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_fifth.png" alt="Fifth Image">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="overlay-content">
                            <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
                            <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="portfolio-list-item img-border mix design col-lg-4">
                <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_sixth.png" alt="Sixth Image">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="overlay-content">
                            <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
                            <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

How I can fix my problem that I will have something that looks like on the second image? Also I can't use border on image because then I will have overlay not only on image but with padding of it.

Comment: I guess this is not connected to apache flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone interested, I changed `.container-fluid` to `.container` and added another div over the `.image-wrapper` and make border for it, and now it's works perfectly fine.

Looks like this:

```
<li class="portfolio-list-item mix illustration col-lg-4">
                <div class="img-border">
                    <div class="image-wrapper">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="images/portfolio_second.png" alt="Second Image">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="overlay-content">
                                <h3 class="overlay-header">Project Title</h3>
                                <a class="overlay-link" href="#">View Project</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put border on `<li class="portfolio-list-item img-border mix web col-lg-4">` and put it on .image-wrapper